# How to replace new lines and spances in notepad++ using regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to use regular expression in Notepad++ to make an SQL log more readable by changing the following output:

```
    208797                                                                      
MARIE-CHRISTINE                                                 
05-JUL-17                                                                       

    208799                                                                      
NICOLE SABA
06-JUL-17                                                                       

    208801                                                                      
HENRI HOUR                                                             
06-JUL-17
```

To something like this:

```
208797 MARIE-CHRISTINE 05-JUL-17
208799 NICOLE SABA 06-JUL-17                                                                       
208801 HENRI HOUR 06-JUL-17
```

I was able to replace space, but I don't know how to replace the rest.

Thank's for help.

Comment: And you tried what?

Comment: You could write a little Autoit Script for that. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make it in two shots :

- `(^\s+|\s+$)` replace all spaces in the start and in the end with empty ([check the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JGpT1X/1))
- `(^.*$)\r\n(^.*$)\r\n(^.*$)` then replace each three successive lines with `$1 $2 $3` ([check the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QmYgPY/1))

---

**Notepade++ eample :**

**Step 1**

[image: Step one]

**Step 2**

[image: Step two]